# How to query in to Couchbase using node-red in post method?

Tags: node.js, post, couchbase, node-red, sql++

I'm trying to connect and run the query to get particular id values in node-red using the post method but facing a problem in attaching post data in the query.

Tried in the following way

API request flow

[image]

Query forming using function node

[image]

After form, the query i need query formation like this

in where condition `c.externalIds.customer_master in ['111','112','113']` like wise

but I'm getting

```
c.externalIds.customer_master in 111,112,113 like wise
```

and my post node is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tricks in form the query like below

1. Concatenated the array values using array.join('","')

   ```
    ${msgNew.join('","')}
   ```
2. then in appended and prepended array open and close symbol

   ```
    [${msgNew.join('","')}]
   ```
3. Now I got the result expected

[image]